# ar.js 3d model doesn't show up

Tags: 3d, augmented-reality, aframe, gltf, ar.js

I've just started learning to create AR scenes with AR.js and I'm having some trouble with loading custom 3D models. I've tried many examples and all of them work perfectly, but once I insert my own model, it just doesn't show up. I used almost the same exact code for the given example and for my 3D model, which is this one:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <script src="https://aframe.io/releases/1.0.0/aframe.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://raw.githack.com/AR-js-org/AR.js/master/aframe/build/aframe-ar.js"></script>
  <body style="margin : 0px; overflow: hidden;">
    <a-scene embedded arjs>
      <a-marker preset="hiro">
        <a-entity
          position="0 0 0"
          <!-- example given in AR.js docs -->
          <!-- scale="0.05 0.05 0.05"
          gltf-model="https://arjs-cors-proxy.herokuapp.com/https://raw.githack.com/AR-js-org/AR.js/master/aframe/examples/image-tracking/nft/trex/scene.gltf"
          -->
          <!-- my 3D model -->
          scale="0.05 0.05 0.5"
          gltf-model="model/scene.gltf"
        ></a-entity>
      </a-marker>
      <a-entity camera></a-entity>
    </a-scene>
  </body>
</html>
```

My page structure:

```
.
|_ index.html
|_ model
   |_ scene.gltf
   |_ scene.bin
```

My model:

https://sketchfab.com/3d-models/coronavirus-covid-19-virus-991102145c294fe4b633faecc23f3799

I've tried many other models, other formats (.dae, .obj, .fbx), changing the scale of the model and nothing seems to work. What could be the problem?

Comment: This looks like malformed HTML.  You have a comment tag in the middle of attributes inside of another tag, I don't think that's allowed.

Comment: I just included that for this question. It is not there when I run my code :)

Comment: Share a link to an example that reproduces your issue. Keep it simple. I will help people to help you. https://glitch.com/~aframe

Comment: https://glitch.com/edit/#!/join/5bb2c2b3-3c9f-47c9-abd0-ce02c1d94c58 @DiegoMarcos here you go, hope it works out

Comment: Make sure your model loads on https://gltf-viewer.donmccurdy.com/

Comment: @DiegoMarcos it does

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The model won't show up because of two factors:

1. The model is huge and off - centered. Scaling it by 0.01 moves it a bit towards the center.

If your model shows up in Dons [gltf-viewer](https://gltf-viewer.donmccurdy.com) - always try out your model in vanilla `a-frame` - at least in a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/w904yg67/). Its easy to inspect, debug, and you can be sure whether `a-frame` is causing the trouble.

2. Glitch assets is not a folder. It may look this way for our convenience, but it's just a bunch of links. So `scene.gltf` is searching for `scene.bin` in its current directory (edit and search the `gltf` file - its human readable), but it's not there.

Replacing the paths with glitch urls is a bad idea (usually there are way more paths than just the `.bin`). You should push the model into a github repository, where the directories work as expected.

Working arjs [glitch here](https://glitch.com/~stack-60816750).

Comment: Just checked that glitch you share using two different Android phones and two different browsers and couldn't see the model in any of them. Also, tested in a dark room and in a space full of light, and rotating all around but couldn't find it

Comment: @TiagoMartinsPeres did you bring a Hiro Marker?

Comment: @dirkk0 ui can't recall. I think so...

Comment: Do you still have issues with models? Just checked the glitch with firefox on android and it seems to be working. Maybe there are some console errors?

Comment: The Glitch is working, even if you update the A-Frame lib to 1.2.0.